# Angular 4 Date-Picker - How to restrict Future and Past Days

Tags: angular, npm, datepicker, calendar, dayofmonth

I want to restrict the future and past days using Angular 4 Date-Picker.I just want to enable Current Date[today] only.How can i solve this.

Can anyone have idea...???

This is my template:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="FromDate" class="form-control" 
  placement="top"
  formControlName="fromDate" 
  [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY' }" 
  bsDatepicker style="padding: 16px">
```

Comment: It depends on how you have implemented your date-picker. Can you post your date-picker code please?

Comment: @rmcsharry  <input type="text"
                   placeholder="FromDate"
                   class="form-control"
                   placement="top"
                   formControlName="fromDate"  [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY' }"
                   bsDatepicker style="padding: 16px">

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[bsDatepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#min-max) has a property `[minDate]` and `[maxDate]`, so you set those to "today" and inside your components constructor you do:

component.ts

`today=new Date();`

component.html

`<input ... bsDatepicker ... [minDate]="today" [maxDate]="today" ... >`

Anyway, having a datepicker when you don't really allow the user to select a date other than today makes no sense, you might as well default it to "today".

Comment: If this answered your question make sure to mark it as accepted or upvote so it can help other people with the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: how to tranform that DATE-FORMAT from "DD-MM-YYYY" into "YYYY-MM-DD" while clicks on submit... my template should be                                         "params.Date = this.LicenseForm.value.Date"

Answer (score 0):

Similar than mentioned above, but in angular according to:
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

component.ts

```js
today = new Date()
```

component.html

```html
<input matInput [min]="today" [max]="today">
```